# Using the fun keyword in ocaml

Tags: function, ocaml

Since Ocaml utilizes type inferences, and functions are a type, do I have to use `fun` to declare a function? For example, the REPL/interpreter for Ocaml executes this statement without complaint:

```
let average a b =
  (a +. b) /. 2.0;;
```

Does this mean that I can dispense with `fun` when declaring functions? When is it needed, or is it ever needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyword `fun` is needed with anonymous functions. For instance, the following code doubles each elements of the list `l = [ 1; 2; 3; 4]`

```
let l = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let doubled_l = List.map (fun x -> 2 * x) l
```

but this snippet could be rewritten as

```
let l = [1; 2; 3; 4]
let double x = 2 * x
let doubled_l = List.map double l
```

( or even `List.map ( ( * ) 2 ) l` )

Contrarily, your average function could be rewritten as

```
let average = fun x y -> (x +. y) /. 2.
```

or

```
let average = fun x -> fun y -> (x +. y) /. 2.
```

(the syntax `average x y = ...` is in fact a syntactic sugar for this form)

Answer (score 2):

`let average a b = ...` is exactly equivalent to `let average = fun a b -> ...` - you can always use the former over the latter. It's just a matter of style which one you prefer. My feeling is that most programmers use the former form, but some introductory materials use the latter form to make it clear that functions are values just like any other and can be created using the `fun` keyword.

However `let f = fun ...` is not the only way to use `fun`. You can use it wherever a value of a function type is expected, for example as an argument to `map`. So if you have something like `List.map (fun x -> x+1) xs`, you can't just put a `let` in place of the `fun` because a definition makes no syntactic sense there. You could of course use `let add1 x = x+1 in List.map add1 xs` and that works fine, but that's more verbose and introduces a new name that's only used once and doesn't really add anything.

So `fun` is useful when you want to pass a function around without giving it a name.